# How to get Min and max values based on the given values?

Tags: javascript

i'll be getting two values bigValue & smallValue based on this I should set maxValue & minValue, below are the conditions explained

```
if bigValue=42 & smallValue=23 then maxValue=50 & minValue=20

if bigValue=12 & smallValue=03 then maxValue=20 & minValue=0

if bigValue=0.156 & smallValue=0.1 then maxValue=0.2 & minValue=0.1

if bigValue=0.0156 & smallValue=0.01 then maxValue=0.02 & minValue=0.01
```

How to achieve this with better logic using only javascript?

Here bigValue & smallValue can be of any values & both will be positive.

I have this requirement to set the start and end point for y-axis in graph.

Comment: Can there be any number of combinations? Could `bigValue 42 come with smallValue 03`, for example?

Comment: What's wrong with the logic you have? (perhaps except for missing `else`?). You probably could put those value in a table and do some sort of a composite key lookup, but I'm not sure whether it's worth it in your case.

Comment: @Matthijs yea that is possible

Comment: What is your question exactly? You don't know how to write this in javascript or different?

Comment: What is the logic behind this? It makes no sense

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I feel it has too many if else

Comment: Here bigValue and smallValue can be any value? Or these specific values?

Comment: @SKADIN Why not using a switch statement?

Comment: @dshgna can be any values but always bigValue>smallValue and both will be positive.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I'm getting the points that should be shown in graph, for which i should set the y-axis accordingly.

Comment: @SKADIN: So you basically want to push up bigValue to the nearest upper 10th and smallValue to the nearest lower 10th?

Comment: @dshgna ya if it is integer, but if it is decimal as in the third condition i should be setting that accordingly.

Comment: are all numbers below 100 or any with no limit ?

Comment: @Munawir can be above

Comment: @SKADIN check if my answer to see if it's what you need. Also, in cases when the numbers are above 100, will they be rounded to the lowest/highest 10th?

Comment: @dshgna i'll check that!! and ya it will be still rounded to the lowest/highest 10th.

Comment: @SKADIN Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35578595/2792083

Comment: @Munawir i'll check that

Comment: @SKADIN Updated answer to satisfy your latest condition.

Answer (score 8):

This proposal works with the logarithm of 10 for the wanted range. It works for small numbers as well, even with one min/max zero value and negative values.

```js
function getBorders(min, max) {
    var v = Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log(Math.max(Math.abs(min), Math.abs(max))) / Math.log(10)));
    return {
        left: Math.floor(min / v) * v || 0,
        right: Math.ceil(max / v) * v || 0
    };
}

var values = [{ "min": 80, "max": 100 }, { "min": 23, "max": 42 }, { "min": 3, "max": 12 }, { "min": 0.1, "max": 0.156 }, { "min": 0.01, "max": 0.0156 }, { "min": 30, "max": 255 }, { "min": 1255, "max": 2784 }, { "min": 0.0023, "max": 0.00769 }, { "min": 0, "max": 0.002 }, { "min": 0, "max": 15000 }, { "min": -23, "max": 0 }, { "min": -123, "max": 2 }, { "min": 0, "max": 0 }];

values.forEach(function (a) {
    var o = getBorders(a.min, a.max);
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) { a[k] = o[k]; });
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: For value min=80 & max = 100, it is coming as left=0 & right=100.I would require it as left=80 & right=100.

Comment: that is then an exeption, because in your original question you are rounding by the most left digit, here its **0**80 and **1**00. the first value get floored to **0**00 and the second gets ceiled and stays at **1**00.

Comment: You can use `console.log` in your answers instead of `document.write` btw, it would show the same formatted output

Comment: @vsync, now it does, but at this time, i wrote the answer, console meant console and i work without console (mostly).

Comment: fails at { "min": 0, "max": 0 }

Comment: @Redu, what do you expect at zero values

Comment: I would expect `[0,0]` but `Math.log(0)` is the problem here :)

Answer (score 3):

If, according to the example cases, your requirement is to set the bigValue to the nearest upper tenth and the smallValue to the nearest lower tenth: the following should work fine for both positive integers and positive decimals.

Using the ternary operator:

```
//if decimal: get the largest non-zero position
if (bigValue< 1) {
   decBig = Math.ceil(-Math.log10(bigValue));}

if (smallValue< 1) {
   decSmall = Math.ceil(-Math.log10(smallValue))};

maxValue =  bigValue >= 1? Math.ceil(bigValue/10) *10 : Math.ceil(bigValue*Math.pow(10,decBig))/Math.pow(10,decBig);
minValue =  smallValue>= 1? Math.floor(smallValue /10) *10 : Math.floor(smallValue*Math.pow(10,decBig))/Math.pow(10,decBig);
```

Comment: If that's indeed what the OP wanted, because his code doesn't do *exactly* that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: OP has specified in his comments and question that bigValue and smallValue can be any positive values.

Comment: My bad!!I missed one more condition,please check.It is failing for fourth.

Comment: @SKADIN I've updated the answer for it to work for any number of decimal places.

Answer (score -1):

This should be your answer :

Try changing the values of the function call parameters

**EDIT** : Snippet updated to satisfy your last condition

```js
function myFun(bigValue, smallValue) {
  var min_val;
  var max_val;
  
  var min = Math.min(bigValue, smallValue);
  var max = Math.max(bigValue, smallValue);
  
  if(parseInt(bigValue)==0) {
       var i = 1;
       while(bigValue < 1){
          bigValue *= 10;
          i *= 10;
       }
       max_val = Math.ceil(bigValue)/i;
  }
  else {
       max_val = Math.ceil(max/10)*10;
  }
  if(parseInt(smallValue)==0) {
       var i = 1;
       while(smallValue < 1){
          smallValue *= 10;
          i *= 10;
       }
       min_val = Math.floor(smallValue)/i;
  }
  else {
       min_val = Math.floor(min/10)*10;
  }
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Max value :" + max_val + ", Min value :" + min_val; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFun(0.156,0.1)">Decimal 1</button>
<button onclick="myFun(0.0156,0.01)">Decimal 2</button>
<button onclick="myFun(42,23)">Integer</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score -3):

Is this what you are looking for ??

```
if (bigValue===42 && smallValue===23){
maxValue=50 ;
 minValue=20;
}
else if(bigValue===12 && smallValue===03){
maxValue=20 ;
 minValue=0;
}
else if( bigValue===0.156 && smallValue===0.1){
maxValue=0.2 ;
 minValue=0.1;
}
```